# Delete empty dictionary from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary A:

```
A =  {"('All', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai')": {}, "('Container', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai')": {}, 
      "('Open', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai')": {12: [12, 22, 25], 7: [9, 5]},
      "('Open', 'Doon', 'Gurgaon')": {10: [1, 2, 24], 8: [4], 9: [28, 8], 7:[21]}}
```

I want to remove all the empty dictionaries, How can I do that ?

Comment: `print({k: v for k, v in A.items() if v})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v  in A.items() if v}
{"('Open', 'Delhi', 'Mumbai')": {12: [12, 22, 25], 7: [9, 5]}, "('Open', 'Doon', 'Gurgaon')": {10: [1, 2, 24], 8: [4], 9: [28, 8], 7: [21]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a comprehension here:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in A.items() if v}
print(new_dict)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/myeDmQ).